# no method in multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The scenario is that u user has_many head_bookings and the head_bookings has_many bookings and the apartments belong to a booking. The head_booking has a ordernumber. So when the user login they get bookings with the apartments group by the head_booking (ordernumber)

The are my models

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :head_bookings
    end



class HeadBooking < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :bookings  
    belongs_to :user
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  belongs_to :appartment
  belongs_to :head_booking
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :head_booking

end
```

I created some dummy data in the tables and i tried this in the console:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.head_bookings
u.head_bookings.bookings
```

With the command u.head_bookings.bookings i get the error "undefined method `bookings'"

What am i doing wrong?? Thanks..remco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on working with the bookings of a user directly, you should add a relation between `User` and `Booking` using `has_many through`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :head_bookings
  has_many :bookings, through: :head_bookings
end
```

This will allow you to do things like `u.bookings` which will fetch all the bookings of the user joining through his head bookings.

Answer (score 1):

You can associate bookings to user.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :head_bookings
  has_many :bookings, through: :head_bookings
end
```

Then you can select bookings of user by:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.bookings
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `User` `has_many :head_bookings` then when you do a `u.head_bookings` it returns a relation (which sort of act as an array), and you can't do a `.bookings` in a array.

Try something like

```
u.head_bookings.each do |hb|
  b.bookings
end
```

To use the `bookings` of each `head_booking`.